# Spyder: An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I have been struggling with this error for days now. I haven't updated anaconda, nor made any config changes . I have tried conda update --all and still isn't working. The error is

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 269, in
main()
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 237, in main
from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in
from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init*_.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in
from copy import deepcopy
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py", line 11, in
import pandas as pd
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas_*init*_.py", line 42, in
from pandas.core.api import *
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby_*init*_.py", line 2, in
from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in
from pandas.core.series import Series
File "C:\Users\ADITHYA\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in
import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

Comment: You need to remove or rename the following file to fix your problem: `C:\Users\ADITHYA.spyder‑py3\selenium udemy\driver\copy.py`.

Comment: Thanks! Was that file causing mismatch in spyder's config files?

Comment: No, the problem is that Python comes with a module called `copy`. so that file was interfering with it.